# Is an L2 function a weak derivative of its integral with variable endpoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Consider $f \in L^2(0,1)$ and $F = \int_0^x f(t) dt \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$. Is it true that $f$ is the weak derivative of $F$, in the sense that given any $g \in \mathcal{C}_c^1([0,1])$, we have $\int Fg' = -\int fg$? This is obviously true if $f$ is continuous, but I'm having trouble proving the general case. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

(Or, in case $f$ is not necessarily the weak derivative of $F$, is there some other way to show that the operator $f \mapsto \int_0^x f(t) dt$ is injective, i.e., if $\int_0^x f(t) dt = 0$ for some $f \in L^2(0,1)$, then $f = 0$ a.e.?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You actually need to verify that formula for $g\in C^1_c((0,1))$, not $C^1_c([0,1])$. This implies that $g(0)=0$, so $g(x)=\int_0^x g'(t)\,dt$. Insert that into $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx$ and apply Fubini.

**Edit:** The OP says he had to make a small change to what I said. For the record, here's exactly what I  had in mind:

Using the fact that $\int_t^1 f=\int_0^1 f-\int_0^t f$, we see
$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 fg&=\int_0^1 f(x)\int_0^x g'(t)\,dtdx
\\&=\int_0^1 g'(t)\int_t^1 f(x)\,dxdt
\\&=\left(\int_0^1 g'\right)\left(\int_0^1 f\right)-\int_0^1g'(t)\int_0^t f(x)\,dxdt
\\&=0-\int_0^1 g'F.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I see the idea. Thanks a lot! (It was my fault. I should have written $g \in \mathcal{C}_c^1((0, 1))$.)

Comment: (However, I tried and found that I should insert $g(x) = - \int_x^1 g’(t) dt$ instead of $g(x) = \int_0^x g’(t) dt$?)

Comment: That will work too - in fact if you do exactly what I said you need to use $\int_0^1 f = \int_0^x f+\int_x^1 f$ at the end -  probably doing it your way just moves that step to the start.

Comment: Downvote? I give up -  what's  the problem with _that_?

Comment: I see. Doing it either way would work. Thanks again!

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, and I voted up - I have no idea why anyone would vote down...